# Logarithms and Exponentials

Tags: calculus

Use the integral definition and properties of definite integrals to show that $\ln(x) < 0$ when $0 < x < 1$, and $\ln(x) > 0$ when $x > 1$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. You'll get a much warmer response from the community if you show what you've tried. Also, please format your mathematics with MathJax; a tutorial is [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What is your definition of $\ln$ ? The property you want to prove is quite straightforward for anyone familiar with logarithms, so I guess you have to prove it from a precise definition.

Comment: Okay what *is* the integral definition?  Now prove that $\int_1^x \frac 1x dx < 0$ if $0 < x < 1$ and that $\int_1^x \frac 1x dx < 0$ if $x > 1$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

You are defining
$$
\ln x = \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t},
$$

so show $\ln x > 0$ whenever $x>1$ by showing that the integrand is non-negative everywhere on the region and bounding it below. Then note that when $x<1$, you have
$$
\ln x=\int_1^x \frac{dt}{t} = -\int_1^{1/x} \frac{du}{u} = -\ln (1/x),
$$
but $\ln(1/x)>0$ by the argument you already did above...